how to turn off Touchscreen mode on UbuntuStudio 24.04?
All the existing help are not correct for UbuntuStudio 24.04
I do not have a touchscreen. It is an older laptop. I accidentally checked the touchscreen box on "System Settings" and all my taskbar got messed up.
The comment when I try to correct the task bar is
"all icons are spaced wider for touchscreen"
I know I have to undo the checkbox in system settings. I do not have to use the terminal, I just need to find where that setting is!

Why can you not uncheck the touchscreen box again?
